# How do I find the filepath for my plist?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, plist

I am trying to load a plist into a UITableView.  I am new to working with pLists and tableViews, but I know i need to use something along these lines.  My problem is though that where "filePath" is, i don't actually know how to put in my pList?

```
list = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Any other suggestions with code how to to do this other than getting the file path would be greatly appreciated.  Such as do i need to put anything in my .h file? Thanks.

Comment: Please, don't ever ask for code here.  It's a very very bad thing that shows you didn't do any research or work yourself.  Also make sure the top level object of your plist is an NSArray if you are using that method.

Comment: @CodaFi I'll ask for code if I want. I did do research. I have been trying to figure this out for the last day searching for tutorials and reading through the apple developer library.  I also said any other suggestions. I did not just ask a question that was bluntly only asking for code only.

Comment: I asked nicely, and now I'll be blunt:  When you ask a question here, you should state the resources you've already used (if any), because we can and do close questions as being duplicates.  Not only is it a plus to your reputation (not literally, but rather a sign of good intentions), but it encourages answers that are a lot more helpful than a link to some external source.  If you'd like a link to the guidelines that states all of this, I'd be happy to oblige.  (PS, [why you shouldn't ask for code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)).

Comment: I think sharing code snippets is awesome.

Comment: @CodaFi You didn't ask, you said "...don't ever ask for code here." But it's okay, I remember when I got mad at people on message boards and tried to give them lessons on following rules.  Keep up the good work!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you've already added a .plist to your project, I've created a class you can add to your project that will get and save information to a given .plist.  It's a functioning singleton, so you can call it from anywhere.

First, create a new NSObject file called "GetAndSaveData", then post the following code into .h:

```
@interface GetAndSaveData : NSObject{
    NSMutableDictionary *allData;
    NSString *path;
}

+(GetAndSaveData *)sharedGetAndSave;
-(NSMutableArray *)arrayForKey:(NSString *)dataList;

-(void)setData:(NSMutableArray *)array ForKey:(NSString *)dataList;

@end
```

and the following code into .m:

```
static GetAndSaveData *sharedGetAndSave;

@implementation GetAndSaveData

-(id)init{

    self = [super init];

    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"]; 


   if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) 
    {
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"]; 

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; 
    }

    allData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path]; 

    return self;
}


-(NSMutableArray *)arrayForKey:(NSString *)dataList{
    NSMutableArray *array = [allData objectForKey:dataList];

    return array;
}

-(void)setData:(NSMutableArray *)array ForKey:(NSString *)dataList{

    [allData setObject:array forKey:dataList];
    [allData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    if(![allData writeToFile:path atomically:YES])
    {
        NSLog(@".plist writing was unsuccessful");

    }

}

+(GetAndSaveData *)sharedGetAndSave{
    if (!sharedGetAndSave) {
        sharedGetAndSave = [[GetAndSaveData alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedGetAndSave;
}

+(id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    if (!sharedGetAndSave) {
        sharedGetAndSave = [super allocWithZone:zone];
        return sharedGetAndSave;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    return self;
}
@end
```

You can change the functions up to get and save different types of data.  You can use it in view controllers by importing the .h file, and doing the following:

```
myMutableArray = [[GetAndSaveData sharedGetAndSave]arrayForKey:myKey];
```